Postgres-instance stopped working "could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device"
I have installed the Crunchydata Postgres operator using the helm chart and I'm using the NFS file system storage as PVC with 200GB data. When I run kubectl get pods, the output shows that 1 instance has stopped working out of 4.
kubectl get pods | grep -E "READY|postgres-instance"
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
abc-postgres-instance1-c7ck-0           3/4     Running            0          32d

The error that I'm encountering is:
2024-07-12 21:20:21,317 INFO:  stderr=2024-07-12 21:20:21.317 UTC [2615762] FATAL:  could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device

Upon further investigation, I found that the /pgdata/pg16_wal is using up all the space.
When I run kubectl exec -it abc-postgres-instance1-c7ck-0 -- bin/bash and then df -h, I get the following output:
Filesystem                                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                                         124G   51G   74G  41% /
tmpfs                                                            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
172.16.215.54:/export/pvc-c862217c-39c4-4be0-a8a1-1717c450b2d1  196G  196G     0 100% /pgdata
/dev/root                                                       124G   51G   74G  41% /tmp
tmpfs                                                            57G   24K   57G   1% /pgconf/tls
tmpfs                                                            57G   24K   57G   1% /etc/database-containerinfo
tmpfs                                                            57G   16K   57G   1% /etc/patroni
tmpfs                                                            57G     0   57G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                            57G   24K   57G   1% /etc/pgbackrest/conf.d
tmpfs                                                            57G   12K   57G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                                                            32G     0   32G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                            32G     0   32G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/firmware

Is there a way to configure the WAL size limit and archive the old WAL files while also deleting the old archived files?

You can't change the running PostgreSQL parameters or get it to archive WAL files if it can't be started in the first place.  You need to have a running server to do either of those things. Is there any other space you can free up, like human readable log files, so that you can at least get the server running?
